# Java option for proxy access to custom http socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

I am using the following java option for my tomcat instance:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.server.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.server.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
```

While my application is able to connect to http://example.com:80 , it won't connect to any socket except for 80 and 443.
I was wondering if there is a special option for granting the proxy access for other custom ports as well.

Update: Stacktrace added below:

```
10:25:08,511 ERROR: Connection failed tohttp://example.com:8180/Interface/example?wsdl
07:43:48,569 ERROR: Error occurred in getProjectsByHttp.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User id not received from presentation module when trying to connect to 'http://www.myapplication.org/detailsidgetter?sessionid=1481891801898186' url
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.usermanager.SessionUtils.connectToDadUsingHTTP(SessionUtils.java:282)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.util.deitemnavigator.HttpIdGetter.getProjectsByHttp(HttpIdGetter.java:76)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.util.deitemnavigator.HttpIdGetter.getItemsAllIds(HttpIdGetter.java:61)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.appspecific.DeItemIdGetterSpecific.getItemsAllIds(DeItemIdGetterSpecific.java:25)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.appspecific.DeItemTableFormSpecific.init(DeItemTableFormSpecific.java:79)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.appspecific.DeItemTableFormSpecific.<init>(DeItemTableFormSpecific.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:274)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:265)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildManagedBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.VariableResolverImpl.resolveVariable(VariableResolverImpl.java:311)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.resolvers.EnumResolver.resolveVariable(EnumResolver.java:36)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.LastVariableResolverInChain.resolveVariable(LastVariableResolverInChain.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl$ELVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ValueBindingImpl.java:574)
    at org.apache.commons.el.NamedValue.evaluate(NamedValue.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.el.ComplexValue.evaluate(ComplexValue.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.el.UnaryOperatorExpression.evaluate(UnaryOperatorExpression.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.el.BinaryOperatorExpression.evaluate(BinaryOperatorExpression.java:166)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.ValueBindingImpl.getValue(ValueBindingImpl.java:383)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:1075)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.renderChildren(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:189)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGridRendererBase.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:536)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeRecursive(RendererBase.java:206)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeChildrenRecursive(RendererBase.java:216)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeRecursive(RendererBase.java:204)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeChildrenRecursive(RendererBase.java:216)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeRecursive(RendererBase.java:204)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.RendererBase.encodeChildrenRecursive(RendererBase.java:216)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.VisibilityRendererHTML.encodeChildren(VisibilityRendererHTML.java:25)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:524)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.encodeChildren(UIComponentTag.java:480)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.doEndTag(UIComponentTag.java:361)
    at org.apache.jsp.master1.de1View_jsp._jspx_meth_sis_005fvisibility_005f0(de1View_jsp.java:531)
    at org.apache.jsp.master1.de1View_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(de1View_jsp.java:396)
    at org.apache.jsp.master1.de1View_jsp._jspService(de1View_jsp.java:346)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:234)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:221)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:202)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:221)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:384)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.init.DADFilter.doFilter(DADFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.beanmanager.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.synisys.taglib.jsf.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:75)
    at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:213)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.core.util.AjaxFilter.doFilter(AjaxFilter.java:45)
    at com.synisys.dad.de.appspecific.AjaxFilter.doFilter(AjaxFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
07:45:01,298 ERROR: Error occurred in getProjectsByHttp.
```

Comment: Could you please post th ecode snippet which fails using the proxy settings. It might be possible that the access is restricted by the used proxy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the codes, but the same code works when the server has direct internet access.

Comment: In the application logs I can see only the following:
Connection failed to http://example.com:8180/Interface/wsdlexample?wsdl

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? Otherwise it would be nothing more then digging in the dark.

Comment: I have added it into the question.